# Disable Checking Out of PDF Files

Tags: versioning, pdf, check-out

We have a client who is having issues with users who are checking out documents instead of picking "Read Only". We would like to find a way to remove the option to have them check out documents and instead just download or open it in browser.

Here is the step by step of what currently happens.

1. Log in to library.
2. Click on PDF.
3. [Open Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al7uB.png) window opens.
4. User picks "Check Out and Edit".
5. PDF is checked out for editing.

We would instead like to remove steps 3 and 4 for only PDF files. This would remove the ability for PDF's to be checked out, edited, etc. as they are considered "Effective" in this environment at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document library's settings, disable "require check out." That way, end users will not be prompted with an option to check out documents.

If your PDFs are mixed in with other documents that you would like users to have the option to check out, consider separating the documents out into separate document libraries.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of -- we'll see if this is doable or not. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't remove the dialogue for us - SharePoint 2010 and Adobe Reader XI